# Multiple ng-views for homepage in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, ngroute, ng-view

Okay i am new to angular, just started working with ngRoute and ngView directives, i have come across something that is an issue for me but i suspect is only an issue due to my lack of expereince in angluar.

I have the following markup(simplified) on my index.html page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample APP</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <nav class="pull-right">...</nav>
    </div>

    <div class="main" ng-view>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above is the default layout structure that my page uses.  Now my issue is for the home page alone, a slider is shown within the div with the class "header".  Like this:

```
<div class="header">
  <nav class="pull-right">...</nav>
  <div class="slider">...</div>
<div>
```

Now this is for the homepage only so i'm totally confused about how to implement this.  Do i need **two** ng-view directives on my index page? eg:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sample APP</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <nav class="pull-right">...</nav>
      <div class="slider" ng-view>...</div>
    </div>

    <div class="main" ng-view>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also if you need to know why i am doing it this way, it is simply because i bought an html template online, now i am trying to integrate angularjs into the template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There would be only single `ng-view` on a single page. It won't possible to have multiple `ng-view`. If you want to load other partials then you need to use `ng-include` directive.

[**Ui-router**](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) best option which has supported the multiple views which can be nested on into the other, you could take the advantage of nested views.

You could have query params here in Angular UI Router like in format `url: '/test?oneParam&twoParam'` whereas this feature doesn't support in `ng-route`

I would suggest you to take switch from `ng-route` to `ui-route`, which has great control over `url`, `templates` & `states`

Comment: I'm soo confused by all this, how do i check if the current page/route/state is home and inject the slider into my view?

Comment: you can have access to current state using `$state` service which will have all the information about `state`, `params` , url like if you do `$state.current.name` will give name of `state` & `$state.params` will contain a collection of parameter which are present in route with there values

Comment: So i put that code inside my controller but then how does the slider template autoload itself on my homepage?

Comment: you need to specify that template inside your `$state` defination with your slider template and controller

Comment: Please show me an example of this, this is all new to me.

Comment: @user3718908 this would be best example of nested state http://plnkr.co/edit/u18KQc?p=preview

Comment: Okay i checked that out and it is an example of a nested state but in the example you need to click a link to see the nested state, my nested state(my slider) should show by  itself when the page loads, any ideas?

Comment: @user3718908 you could use ` $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");` to load your default state, that state will load your template & controller

Comment: Sorry you've been very helpful but i still don't get it, will continue looking for something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76930/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-user3718908).

Comment: Hello thank you for your help, i read through all the stuff you showed me and i was able to implement what i wanted to do. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can only have one `ng-view`.

However , it is possible to change its content in several ways: `ng-include`, `ng-switch` or mapping different controllers and templates through the routeProvider.

You can also look into using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), which allows for multiple parallel views.

Here is an [example of multiple views using ui-router](http://plnkr.co/edit/SDOcGS?p=preview).

Comment: This may be asking for too much but since i am new can i get an example of what i want to achieve?

Comment: @user3718908 just added an example for you.