# asp.net angular app nav bar not being updated

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

In my app I am getting data from server including the menu items. So each item has its own menu items. The thing is the menu items are not being updated as they should be. When I check in the JS side the menu items do updated in accordance to the current item being displayed but the menu items in the view (html) are not being updated.

Here is my html code

```
    <div ng-app="WebInterfaceApp">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="owl-carousel visible-xs" carousel  ng-controller="HomeController">
            <carousel-item ng-repeat="page in movies.pages" ng-class="{'active': selectedMenu == page.name }" class="item sliderImage">
                <div id="sliderImage">
                    <a class="my_menu" data-toggle="tab" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="topMenuAction(page.name, $index)">{{page.name}}</a>
                </div>
            </carousel-item>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <ajaxloader></ajaxloader>

    <div id="ui-view" ui-view></div>
</div>
```

My JS code is this

```
angular.module('WebInterfaceApp', ['ui.router','youtube-embed','ngTouch'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
$stateProvider
.state('All', {
    url: '/:itemId',
    templateUrl: '/Home/Landing',
    controller: 'HomeController'
}).state('Landing', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: '/Home/Landing',
    controller: 'HomeController'
});

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$httpProvider.defaults.timeout = 10000;
}])
.service('WebInterfaceService', ['$http', function ($http) {
console.log("webservice");
this.getTagItems = function (tag) {



    return fromAPi;
};
this.getTagItemPage = function (tag, page, pageNo) {
    return fromAPi;
};

this.startLoader = function () {
    $('ajaxLoader').css('position', 'absolute');
    $('ajaxLoader').height($('[ui-view]').height() < 100 ? $(window).height() : $('[ui-view]').height());
    $('ajaxLoader').width($('[ui-view]').width() < 100 ? $(window).width() : $('[ui-view]').width());
    $('ajaxLoader').html('<div style="z-index: 999;position: absolute;margin-top: 20%;margin-left: 50%;"><img src="~/Content/images/ajax-loader.gif" />LOADING...</div>').show();
};
this.stopLoader = function () {
    $('ajaxLoader').hide();
};

}])
.controller('HomeController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', 'WebInterfaceService', function ($rootScope, $scope, $location, WebInterfaceService) {    
$scope.flag = true;
if ($location.path() == '/') {
    $location.path('United Kingdom');
}
$scope.setData = function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.movies = data;
};
$rootScope.selectedMenu = 'Overview';
$scope.topMenuAction = function (name, index) {
    // Begin our infinite scroll from the top
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    $rootScope.selectedMenu = name;
    // Load sections for current page
    var page = $scope.movies.pages[index];
    page.sectionsLoaded = false;
    $scope.sectionManage(index);
    //window.scrollTo(0, 1); //TODO - needs to be fixed as doesn't work on a phone per Chrome 
};
$scope.linkAction = function (act) {
    $location.path(act);
};
$scope.tagAction = function (tag) {
    WebInterfaceService.getTagItems(tag)
        .success(function (tagItems) {
            $scope.movies = tagItems;
            var scope = angular.element($('[ng-controller="HomeController"]')).scope();
            scope.setData(tagItems);

            // Load sections for the first page
            $scope.sectionManage(0);
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load movie data: ' + error.message;
            console.log($scope.status);
        });
};
$scope.tagAction($location);  
$scope.test =function(){
    console.log("hover");
};
$scope.pageManage = function(direction,page,index){
    if (page !== undefined && $scope.flag === true) {
        $scope.topMenuAction(page, index);
    }
    else{
        console.log("You are now in last/First");
    }
    console.log("direction-"+direction+'page-'+page);
};
// Function for loading sections for specific page in background
$scope.sectionManage = function (pageIndex) {

    // If index is out of bound, just return
    if (pageIndex >= $scope.movies.pages.length)
        return;
    // Internal loop function, which is called after every ajax request if we need to load more sections
    var loop = function () {
        var page = $scope.movies.pages[pageIndex];
        // Number of section which will be loaded next
        var pageNo = page.sections.length;
        // If we already loading some sections, or already loaded all available sections, just return
        if (page.loadingSections || page.sectionsLoaded)
            return;
        // Set this as true to avoid many background requests
        page.loadingSections = true;

        WebInterfaceService.getTagItemPage($location, pageIndex, pageNo)
        .success(function (sections) {
            // Add each received section to our page
            angular.forEach(sections, function (section) {
                page.sections.push(section);
            });
            // Set this as false to be able load new sections on the next time
            page.loadingSections = false;
            // If we get some sections
            if (sections.length > 0) {
                // And our bottom anchor is still visible (which means that we have empty space from the bottom)
                if ($scope.isBottomAnchorInViewport()) {
                    // Go to another iteration and call the function again
                    loop();
                }
            } else {
                // If we get empty sections array, that all available sections already loaded
                page.sectionsLoaded = true;
            }
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to load page data: ' + error.message;
            console.log($scope.status);
            page.loadingSections = false;
        })
    }
    // Trigger this function for first iteration
    loop();
};
// Function for checking that our bottom anchor is still visible or not (which means that we have empty space from the bottom)
$scope.isBottomAnchorInViewport = function () {
  /*  var rect = angular.element('#bottomAnchor')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight+500 || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    ); */
};
```

}])

Comment: Try `$scope.$apply();` where you set your movies var.

Comment: In     $scope.setData function?

Comment: I tried that in setData function but it didn't worked. It started showing errors on console.

Comment: where you call `$scope.setData`  function? you have just initialize it but didn't call.

Comment: From no where I think, its called automatically whenever I click a link to a different page it is called.

Comment: It wont. You should call the function. Please check my answer.

Comment: @RameshRajendran did you understood mate?

Comment: Okay cool. The problem is you has been using your home controller before the `ng-view` will be run.  kindly check this [Multiple ng-views for homepage in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038565/multiple-ng-views-for-homepage-in-angularjs)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153765/discussion-between-chaudhry-mohsin-ali-and-ramesh-rajendran).

Comment: As I am quite new to angular I am not really sure how to fix this and even what the issue is. Can you explain a bit more?